# Adding space in javascript timer

Tags: javascript

I have script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
     $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
       var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
       + '<span class="week">%-w</span>w : '
       + '<span class="days">%-d</span>d : '
       + '<span class="hour">%H</span>h : '
       + '<span class="mini">%M</span>m : '
       + '<span class="sec">%S</span>s'));
     });
  });
</script>
```

it shows my timer like:

`4w:2d:14h:10m:26s`

What I want is to add space before and after `:` so can be like:

`4w : 2d : 14h : 10m : 26s`

how do i do that?

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: @Dipakchavda `<span class="clock" data-countdown="{{$discount->value_to}}"></span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you content adding section code with `&nbsp;`:

```
var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
       + '<span class="week">%-w</span>w&nbsp;:&nbsp;'
       + '<span class="days">%-d</span>d&nbsp;:&nbsp;'
       + '<span class="hour">%H</span>h&nbsp;:&nbsp;'
       + '<span class="mini">%M</span>m&nbsp;:&nbsp;'
       + '<span class="sec">%S</span>s'));
```

Comment: your way working i also tried space with keyboard work (just type ` : `) that works also, but i used your way :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is what CSS is for.

With it you can dynamically control its formatting based on portrait/landscape etc.

```css
.days::before, .hour::before, .mini::before, .sec::before {
  content: ':';
  padding: 0 6px 0 3px; 
}
```

```html
<span class="week">4w</span>
<span class="days">2d</span>
<span class="hour">14h</span>
<span class="mini">10m</span>
<span class="sec">26s</span>
```

---

If you have a wrapper for those `span`'s, you can do this

```css
.datetime span:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: ':';
  padding: 0 6px 0 3px; 
}
```

```html
<span class="datetime">
  <span class="week">4w</span>
  <span class="days">2d</span>
  <span class="hour">14h</span>
  <span class="mini">10m</span>
  <span class="sec">26s</span>
</span>
```

---

And add the letters

If you have a wrapper for those `span`'s, you can do this

```css
.datetime span:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: ':';
  padding: 0 6px 0 3px; 
}
.week::after {
  content: 'w';
}
.days::after {
  content: 'd';
}
.hour::after {
  content: 'h';
}
.mini::after {
  content: 'm';
}
.sec::after {
  content: 's';
}
```

```html
<span class="datetime">
  <span class="week">4</span>
  <span class="days">2</span>
  <span class="hour">14</span>
  <span class="mini">10</span>
  <span class="sec">26</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @mafortis It is useful today :)